# Show that a certain complex power series satisfies $f'(w)=\frac{f(w)}{2w}$

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, power-series, recursion

Suppose $$a_{n+1}=\left(\frac 1 2 - n\right)a_n$$ with $a_0=1$ defines a real sequence of numbers.

I am then given that the following complex power series is differentiable on $D(1,1)$:
$$ f(w)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}(w-1)^n.$$
I know how to differentiate complex power series on the disk with radius $1$. Its derivative is given by:
$$f'(w)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{a_n}{n!}(w-1)^{n-1}.$$

$$f'(w)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!}(w-1)^{n-1}.$$
An index shift gives us:
$$f'(w)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{a_{k+1}}{k!}(w-1)^{k}.$$
Which almost is the original series again, apart from an incremented coefficient.

Now I am asked to show the following relation:

> $f'(w)=\frac{f(w)}{2w}$

But I do not see how I can possibly get there from what I have. I tried binomial expansion and using the recursion, but by using the recursion I get two terms and I'm struggling to make it one single series again. Any insights/hints?

Comment: When you computed the derivative
$$f'(w)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{a_{k+1}}{k!}(w-1)^{k}.$$
you forgot where the $a_n$ come from


$$a_{k+1}=\left(\frac 1 2 - k\right)a_k$$
You never used that, actually

Comment: I mean, why did they define $a_n$ like that?

Comment: I solved the ODE $f'(w)=\frac{f(w)}{2w};\;f(0)=0$ and got $f(w)=\sqrt w$ which is also the result of the series. For the last result I used *Mathematica*, to be honest...

Comment: Yes the point is to work up to a definition of the complex square root. The exercise in the book first asks to give existence via the inverse function theorem and then gives a series that approximates the inverse of $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disk centred at $1$

Comment: How does mathematica make the assumption that $w$ is complex?

Comment: I solved the recurrence $$a_n=-\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$$ and then I got $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{a_n (w-1)^n}{n!}=\sqrt{w}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that:
$$ f'(w) =\sum_{n =1} ^\infty n \frac{a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n-1} =\sum_{n=1} ^\infty  \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} (w-1)^{n-1}.$$
We are now asked to show:
$$ f'(w) = \frac{1}{2w}f(w).$$
This is equivalent to:
$$ 2w f'(w) = f(w).$$
Which can be written as:
$$ 2((w-1) +1) f'(w) = f(w).$$
This is what we will prove instead. We fill in $f '(w)$:
$$2wf'(w) =  2((w-1) +1)\sum_{n =1} ^\infty n \frac{a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n-1}.
$$
We work out the brackets:
$$2wf'(w)= \sum_{n =1} ^\infty \frac{2 n a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n} + \sum_{n =1} ^\infty  \frac{2 a_n}{(n-1)!} (w-1)^{n-1}.$$
We apply an index shift in the second series:
$$2wf'(w)= \sum_{n =1} ^\infty \frac{2 n a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n} + \sum_{n =0} ^\infty \frac{2 a_{n+1}}{n!}(w-1)^{n}.$$
We combine the power series:
$$2wf'(w)=\frac{2 a_1}{0!}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2 na_{n}+2 a_{n+1}}{n!} (w-1)^{n}.$$
Since $a_0=1$ we have $a_1=(1/2-0)a_0=1/2 \cdot 1=1/2.$ So $2a_1=1$, we also see that $a_{n+1}=(1/2-n)a_n \implies a_{n+1}+ n a_n= 1/2 a_n $ and thus $a_n=2na_n + 2a_{n+1}$. This is precisely what appears in our power series. We see that:
$$2wf'(w)=\frac{2 a_1}{0!}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2 na_{n}+2 a_{n+1}}{n!} (w-1)^{n}=1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n}, $$
$$2wf'(w) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} (w-1)^{n} = f(w)  .$$
This then in turn is equivalent to out desired equality:
$$ f'(w) = \frac{1}{2w} f(w). \quad \square $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(z)=f(1+z)$. Then the identity to be shown is
$$2 g'(z) = \frac{g(z)}{1+z}\text{.}$$

To show this identity, consider the the Chu-Vandermonde identity:

$$\binom{\alpha+\beta}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{\alpha}{k}\binom{\beta}{n-k}\text{.}$$

Let $\alpha=\tfrac{1}{2}$, $\beta=-1$. Since

$$\binom{-1}{k}=(-1)^k$$
it follows that

$$\binom{-\tfrac{1}{2}}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{\tfrac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\text{.}$$

Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\tfrac{1}{2}}{n}z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{\tfrac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\right)z^n\text{,}$$
an equation which is equivalent to the required identity.